# Core Location doesn't work with Apple watch

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, core-location, gpx

I have a GPX file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx
  version="1.0"
  creator="GPSBabel - http://www.gpsbabel.org"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd">
<time>2015-04-03T15:04:33Z</time>
<bounds minlat="32.994533333" minlon="35.573600000" maxlat="33.176883333" maxlon="35.630866667"/>
<trk>
  <name>GNSSALTTRK</name>
  <desc>IGCHDRS~HFFXA035~HFPLTPILOTINCHARGE: pilot~HFCM2CREW2: not recorded~HFGTYGLIDERTYPE:unknown~HFGIDGLIDERID:unknown~HFDTM100GPSDATUM: WGS-1984~HFRFWFIRMWAREVERSION: 1.00~HFRHWHARDWAREVERSION: 2012~HFFTYFRTYPE: ParaWind by Dr. Edgar Bolender~HFGPSGPS:Smartphone~HFPRSPRESSALTSENSOR: Smartphone~HFCIDCOMPETITIONID:~HFCCLCOMPETITIONCLASS:~</desc>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="33.060316667" lon="35.625166667">
  <ele>88.000000</ele>
  <time>2014-08-23T03:58:58Z</time>
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="33.061700000" lon="35.624750000">
  <ele>81.000000</ele>
  <time>2014-08-23T03:59:11Z</time>
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="33.062650000" lon="35.624250000">
  <ele>83.000000</ele>
  <time>2014-08-23T03:59:21Z</time>
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="33.064316667" lon="35.624033333">
  <ele>88.000000</ele>
  <time>2014-08-23T03:59:37Z</time>
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="33.065833333" lon="35.623866667">
  <ele>86.000000</ele>
  <time>2014-08-23T03:59:51Z</time>
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="33.066983333" lon="35.623500000">
  <ele>84.000000</ele>
  <time>2014-08-23T04:00:02Z</time>
</trkpt>
....
```

I added it to the current scheme and run it but got no location change.
I suspected that it related to the old timeTags but even after changing the system time to the related GPX file times it didn't trigger the location events.

Now I suspect that I am doing something wrong with my model because the app does not ask the user to use the location (It's an app for Apple watch)

```
#import "LocationModel.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface LocationModel ()<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager* locationManager;

@end

@implementation LocationModel
static LocationModel* sharedInstance;
@synthesize locationManager;

#pragma mark - private

- (void)startStandardUpdates
{
    // Create the location manager if this object does not
    // already have one.
    if (nil == locationManager)
    {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    // Set a movement threshold for new events.
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 1; // meters

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    // Start heading updates.
    if ([CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) {
        locationManager.headingFilter = 5;
        [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    }
}


#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power.
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0) {
        // If the event is recent, do something with it.
        NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
              location.coordinate.latitude,
              location.coordinate.longitude);
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {
    if (newHeading.headingAccuracy < 0)
        return;

    // Use the true heading if it is valid.
    CLLocationDirection  theHeading = ((newHeading.trueHeading > 0) ?
                                       newHeading.trueHeading : newHeading.magneticHeading);
    NSLog(@"Heading changed: %f", theHeading);
    //self.currentHeading = theHeading;
    //[self updateHeadingDisplays];
}

#pragma mark - Init

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self startStandardUpdates];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - public

+(LocationModel*)getSharedInstance
{
    if(!sharedInstance)
    {
        sharedInstance = [[LocationModel alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

+(void)myInit
{
    sharedInstance = [[LocationModel alloc] init];
}

@end
```

I just call myInit from awakeWithContext of the interfaceController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Location need to be implemented in the ios App and not in the extension (as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/iOSSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH21-SW1)).
Another thing, in IOS8 you should call requestWhenInUseAuthorization before calling startUpdatingLocation.

// Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

About the GPX file - the simulator seems not to like it. It just doesn't play.